Updating one slider in plotly affects both subplots
I'm trying to learn plotting interactively in jupyter notebooks using plotly. I wrote a script that generates 2 subplots and 2 sliders. One slider is supposed to control the one subplot, the other slider is supposed to control the other subplot.
One slider changes the std of a 2D Gaussian, plotted as a Surface Plot (works).
The other slider changes the frequency of a plotted sine curve, plotted via Scatter (partly works).
The problem I have is that when I change the frequency of the since curve, the 2D Gaussian in the Surface plot moves, which I neither expect or want.
Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

# Create subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "scatter"}, {"type": "surface"}]])


# Initial values
xx = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
initial_frequency = 1
initial_std = 1

# Initial plot of sine wave (store the trace for later updating)
sine_trace = go.Scatter(x=xx, y=np.sin(initial_frequency * xx))
fig.add_trace(sine_trace, row=1, col=1)

# Initial plot of 2D Gaussian (store the trace for later updating)
x_gaussian = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y_gaussian = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)  # Create a separate copy for Gaussian
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_gaussian, y_gaussian.copy())  # Use the copy in meshgrid
z_gaussian = np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2) / (2 * initial_std**2)) / (2 * np.pi * initial_std**2)
gaussian_trace = go.Surface(x=x_gaussian, y=y_gaussian.copy(), z=z_gaussian)  # Use the copy here too
fig.add_trace(gaussian_trace, row=1, col=2)

# Create slider steps for frequency (sine wave)
frequency_steps = []
for freq_val in np.arange(0.1, 5.1, 0.1):
    y_sine = np.sin(freq_val * xx)
    step1 = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"y": [y_sine]}],  # Update the 'y' of the sine wave
        label=str(freq_val)
    )
    frequency_steps.append(step1)

# Create slider steps for standard deviation (Gaussian surface)
std_steps = []
for std_val in np.arange(0.1, 2.1, 0.1):
    z_std = np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2) / (2 * std_val**2)) / (2 * np.pi * std_val**2)
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"z": [z_std]}],  # Update the 'z' of the Gaussian surface
        label=str(std_val)
    )
    std_steps.append(step)

std_slider = dict(
    active=initial_std - 0.1,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Std: "},
    pad={"t": 50, "b": 10},  # Adjust padding
    steps=std_steps,
    y=0.21,
    font={"size": 9}  # Adjust font size
)

# Add sliders
frequency_slider = dict(
    active=initial_frequency - 0.1,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50, "b": 10},  # Adjust padding
    steps=frequency_steps,
    y=0,
    font={"size": 9}  # Adjust font size
)

fig.update_layout(sliders=[std_slider, frequency_slider])

fig.show()

I tried to generate copys of the parameters to avoid interaction but it did not help

Actually the two sliders updates the two traces, but when moving the SD slider there is no visible glitch on the sine subplot because it doesn't have a z axis.
This happens because, by default, if we don't specify in args which trace(s) should be affected by the slider steps method, the method applies to all traces. See for reference the call signature of Plotly.update() (nb. this is Plotly.js API) :
Plotly.update(graphDiv, data_update, layout_update, [, traceIndices])

By the way I suggest you use Plotly.restyle() instead if you don't need to update the layout, the signature is :
Plotly.restyle(graphDiv, data_update [, traceIndices])


In plotly.py this translates to :
# ...

# Create slider steps for frequency (sine wave)
frequency_steps = []
for freq_val in np.arange(0.1, 5.1, 0.1):
    y_sine = np.sin(freq_val * xx)
    step1 = dict(
        method="restyle",
        args=[
            {"y": [y_sine]}, # Update the 'y' 
            [0]              # of the sine wave 
        ],  
        label=str(freq_val)
    )
    frequency_steps.append(step1)

# Create slider steps for standard deviation (Gaussian surface)
std_steps = []
for std_val in np.arange(0.1, 2.1, 0.1):
    z_std = np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2) / (2 * std_val**2)) / (2 * np.pi * std_val**2)
    step = dict(
        method="restyle",
        args=[{
            "z": [z_std]},  # Update the 'z'
            [1]             # of the Gaussian surface
        ],  
        label=str(std_val)
    )
    std_steps.append(step)

# ...

